# Play NoSuchMethodError when generating Ebean DDL for Maven Dependency

Tags: maven, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a simple Play (2.2.1) application with a (local) Maven dependency that contains an annotated entity. I am using Ebean, which recognizes the entity and works fine with

evolutionplugin=disabled

in application.conf. But when I enable evolutions I get a NoSuchMethodError. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
[error] application - 

! @6gbh417nl - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoSuchMethodError: com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.DdlGenerator: method <init>()V not found]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:152) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.ddl.DdlGenerator: method <init>()V not found
        at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.generateEvolutionScript(EbeanPlugin.java:105) ~[play-java-ebean_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:85) ~[play-java-ebean_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
```

Comment: FYI when I move the entity from the into the play project (and remove the dependency) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My dependency was using an older version of ebean than the play app. Upgrading fixed the problem.